# DB2: What's the fast way to drop a big partitioned table?

Tags: db2

We got a partitioned table with 100000000+ rows, when I drop it it takes 10+ hours and finally failed.

how to speed drop command up ?

Comment: How are you dropping the table?  What is the error you get?

Answer (score 0):

You could issue a `TRUNCATE` against the table. Or detach the partitions and do the same.

There are also some pointers from [DB2 veteran Ember Crooks about deleting data in one of her blog entries](http://db2commerce.com/2012/07/12/how-to-delete-data-from-a-db2-table-and-release-disk-space/). I find her tips and tricks quite helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a Linux command line you could also use

```
db2 LOAD FROM /dev/null of del REPLACE INTO MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE
```

This is the hard way to empty a table, even if it's being referenced by a foreign key. It does however leave the table in an invalid state (since you may have broken referential integrity). Your table won't be accessible untill you issue the set integrity command (for this and dependant tables):

```
SET INTEGRITY FOR  MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE IMMEDIATE CHECKED
```